# get key name and values of a nested JSON object if element is not object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object whose keys I don't know but structure is basically the same. Value can be a string or another object of strings/objects. Here is an example:

```
d = {
  "name": "Sam",
  "grade": 9,
  "classes": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  "age": null
}
```

What I want now is if value is not another object, get the key name and its value. If value is null, return empty string. From the above the expected output is:

```
name=Sam, grade=9, a=1, b=2, age=''
```

Here since classes is object, it has to be looped again to get keys (a,b) and values (1,2).

I tried the following but it gives if any of the values is null, it returns an error:

```
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

It works well if there is no null value:

```
function getKeyValues(data) {
  var q = '';

  f(data);

  function f(s) {
    Object.keys(s).forEach(function(key) {
      if (typeof s[key] === 'object') {
        f(s[key]);
      } else {
        q = q + key + '=' + (s[key] == null) ? "" : s[key] + '&';
      }
    });
  }
  return q;
}

d = {
  "name": "Sam",
  "grade": 9,
  "classes": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  "age": null
}

console.log(getKeyValues(d));
```

Comment: `null` is `typeof` `"object"` but it does not have properties so `Object.keys(null)` fails

Comment: it seems `function f(s){
            Object.keys(s).forEach(function(key) {
                if(s[key] && typeof s[key]==='object'){
                    f(s[key]);
                }
                else{
                    q += key + '=' + ((s[key] == null) ? "" : s[key]) + '&';
                }

            });
        }`

Comment: For recursive situations like this, I'd recommend to add some `console.log` along the way to debug your code to find out where the input becomes null

Comment: @IsaacAbramowitz I am lost on it but yes, it becomes null if s[key]=null which makes sense cos s[key]  is a value. Now if I pass just s, the loop goes on forever. If I check for s[key]==null && s[key]===object, nothing ever returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
function getKeyValues(data) {
    var q = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        var value = data[key];
        if (value == null) {
            q.push(key + "=''");
        } else if (typeof value == "object") {
            q.push(getKeyValues(value));
        } else {
            q.push(key + "=" + value);
        }
    }
    return q.join(",");
}
```

Comment: @Nie Selam good to know :) . I made some readability improvement on the code.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the `reduce` method. Personally I find it a little bit cleaner.

```
function getKeyValues(d) {
    return Object.keys(d).reduce((memo, key) => {
        if (!d[key]) {
            memo[key] = '';
        } else if (typeof d[key] === 'object') {
            Object.keys(d[key]).forEach((subKey) => {
                memo[subKey] = d[key][subKey];
            })
        } else {
            memo[key] = d[key];
        }
        return memo;
    }, {})
}
```

Also, while your question is very clear, I must say that it also makes me a little bit wary. You could find yourself in some difficult debugging situations if property names are ever repeated in nested objects. For example, if

```
d={"name":"Sam","grade":9,"buddy":{"name":"Jeff","age":12}}
```

would you expect name be "Sam" or "Jeff"? A function that answers your question could return either, so that is something to be aware of going forward.